# loop over 2d subplot as if it's a 1-D

Tags: python, matplotlib, flatten, subplot

I'm trying to plot many data using subplots and I'm NOT in trouble but I'm wondering if there is a convenience method to do this.

below is the sample code.

```
import numpy as np    
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

quantities=["sam_mvir","mvir","rvir","rs","vrms","vmax"
,"jx","jy","jz","spin","m200b","m200c","m500c","m2500c"
,"xoff","voff","btoc","ctoa","ax","ay","az"]

# len(quantities) = 21, just to make the second loop expression 
# shorter in this post.

ncol = 5
nrow = math.ceil(21 / ncol)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = nrow, ncols=ncol, figsize=(8,6))

for i in range(nrow):
    for j in range(((21-i*5)>5)*5 + ((21-i*5)<5)*(21%5)):
        axes[i, j].plot(tree[quantities[i*ncol + j]]) 
        axes[i, j].set_title(quantities[i*ncol + j])
```

This code loops over a 2D array of subplots and stops at the 21st plot leaving 4 panels empty. 
My question is that, is there any built-in method to do this task? 
For example, make 2D subplot array and "flatten" the array into 1D then loop over 1D array through 0 to 20.

The expression in the second range() is very ugly. I don't think I'm going to use this code.
I think the trivial way is to count the number of plots and break if count > 21. 
But I just wonder if there is a better (or fancy) way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather than creating your subplots in advance using `plt.subplots`, just create them as you go using `plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, number)`. The small example below shows how to do it. It's created a 3x3 array of plots and only plotted the first 6.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nrows, ncols = 3, 3

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)

fig = plt.figure()    
for i in range(1,7):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, i)
    ax.plot(x, x**i)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

You could fill the final three in of course by doing `plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i)` but not calling any plotting in there (if that's what you wanted).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nrows, ncols = 3, 3

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)

fig = plt.figure()    
for i in range(1,10):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, i)
    if i < 7:
        ax.plot(x, x**i)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example 2]

You may also like the look of [`GridSpec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

Comment: Ah..... That's why I could find anything that seems to answer my question...! The question was just invalid. Thanks a lot! That was quick.

Comment: If you are going to do it this way you should at least use `fig.add_subplot` to make sure that the state machine does not fight back.

Comment: If you want to get nicely laid out graphs, use `fig.tight_layout()`.

Answer (score 21):

`subplots` returns an ndarray of axes objects, you can just flatten or ravel it:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = nrow, ncols=ncol, figsize=(8,6))
for ax in axes.flatten()[:20]:
    # do stuff to ax
```