# overlapping extra ticks and labels from different scale shown

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot multiple subpolts with matplotlib, but having trouble with extra scales showing up. I wanted `ax.label_outer()` to just show the outer labels which it seems to be, but there's an extra set of ticks on the x and y axes, both 0-1, which I don't need. Are they the defaults? From where? Could someone please tell me how to get rid of them?

```
#%%
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%config InlineBackend.figure_format ='retina'

#%%
nrows, ncols = 2, 3

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070906/loop-over-2d-subplot-as-if-its-a-1-d
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(20,10), sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.4, wspace=.2, top=.90)
num = 1

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
num = 1

for ax in axes.flatten()[:5]:

    stationName = 'Title - ' + str(num)

    ax = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, num)
    #plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    #plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)


    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
    #ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    #ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    plt.title(stationName, loc='center', fontsize=15, fontweight=0, color='green' )
    num = num + 1
fig.delaxes(axes[-1,-1])
fig.suptitle('Temperature', fontsize=20)


for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='Years', ylabel='Records') 

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.label_outer()   
# https://towardsdatascience.com/all-your-matplotlib-questions-answered-420dd95cb4ff    
plt.show();
```

[image: Extra ticks and labels in matplotlib]

Comment: It seems that for each axes already present in `axes` you add another axes (via `.add_subplot`) at the same position of that existing axes. So you have two axes per subplot-position.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but I had to change the way I write the Title a little bit. Can I thank you somehow to give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

@ImportanceofBeingEarnest's answer helped me, and I just had to edit how I create the title. My new code is:

```
#%%
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%config InlineBackend.figure_format ='retina'

#%%
nrows, ncols = 2, 3

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070906/loop-over-2d-subplot-as-if-its-a-1-d
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(20,10), sharex=False, sharey=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.4, wspace=.2, top=.90)
num = 1

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
num = 1

for ax in axes.flatten()[:5]:

    stationName = 'Title - ' + str(num)
    ax.plot(x,y,color='blue')
    ax.plot(x,-y,color='red' )
    ax.yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
    ax.set(xlabel='Years', ylabel='Records') 
    ax.set_title(stationName, fontdict={'fontsize': 15, 'fontweight': 0, 'color':'green', 'ha':'center'}) 
    num = num + 1
fig.delaxes(axes[-1,-1])
fig.suptitle('Temperature', fontsize=20)

plt.show();
```